# Julia: How to make HTTP.jl serve from WSL2 VM's ip?

Tags: http, julia, wsl-2

I started a simple http server on WSL2 to serve simple HTML page at localhost:8081.

I would like to have access to this via localhost:8081 (or whatever the URL is) on the host machine.

I followed the instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions.

I used `ip addr | grep eth0` to find the IP under inet and then I started a simple HTTP server in Python and Julia

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

the python version above works with no issues but the Julia server just doesn't work.

```
using HTTP
using HTTP: Sockets, @ip_str
HTTP.serve() do request::HTTP.Request
   @show request
   @show request.method
   @show HTTP.header(request, "Content-Type")
   @show HTTP.payload(request)
   try
       return HTTP.Response("Hello")
   catch e
       return HTTP.Response(404, "Error: $e")
   end
end
```

which opens port 8000 and 8081 for HTTP traffic. Then I went to the host machine and did `localhost:8081` and `$WSL2VMIP:8081`

Neither worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Julia, you seem to need to provide the IP of the WSL2 VM. Get the IP using `ip addr | grep eth0` and look for IP like `172.69.13.20/20` and set `myip = ip"172.69.13.20"`

Note that using `ip"0.0.0.0"` is convenient but it may be **INSECURE** (e.g. at a public cafe) so use with care.

```
using HTTP
using HTTP: @ip_str
HTTP.serve(myip) do request::HTTP.Request
   @show request
   @show request.method
   @show HTTP.header(request, "Content-Type")
   @show HTTP.payload(request)
   try
       return HTTP.Response("Hello")
   catch e
       return HTTP.Response(404, "Error: $e")
   end
end
```